# Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender' does not have a public property named 'EnableSanitization'

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor, htmleditorkit

as i am beginner here i used html editor but it works perfectly on local but on server it shows me this error
Type `'AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender'` does not have a public property named '`EnableSanitization`'.

and i have one property in it `EnableSanitization="false"` but i don't know whats wrong in it

Comment: i used html editor in asp web form

Comment: Would you please clarify how do you check this property? What version of the toolkit you are using? Can you provide a sample code?